# How Can I remove the child component from parent in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am creating the child component dynamically based on the data length. for first time its showing the  the child component data properly, when any change of data I have to display changed data components but unable to clear the already child component render data. On data change I am making fieldData = [] but its not working, I need to clear entire child objects on change of field data. I am getting the change event of field data, but not sure how to clear the child components. Any idea on how to clear the child components. Thanks..

```
<template for:each={fieldData} for:item="field">
   <template if:false={field.hidden}>
       <c-child input-element={field} object-name={object} key={field.sequence}>
           </c-child>
    </template>
</template>
```

in JS:

```
removeChilds(){
    let childComponents = this.template.querySelectorAll('c-child');
    // how to remove the childComponents from parent...
}
```

Comment: please also add the code for clearing fieldData.
From what I understood you just want to empty the list and re-render it correctly?

Comment: You can't add or remove elements dynamically directly in LWC JavaScript. This is a limitation of LWC. Whatever it is you're trying to do, you're doing it incorrectly, otherwise it would work to simply assign the property a new value. We need to see more code in order to help you uncover the problem. As written, this is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Setting they this.fieldData = [] should clear the data.  Some earlier versions you just had to make sure that the @track decoration was used when defining the array.